# Failed to resolve: :truesdk-0.7-releasePartner

Tags: java, android, kotlin, truesdk

I am trying to add the truecaller sdk. But I'm facing this error:

> Failed to resolve: :truesdk-0.7-releasePartner

I have Googled it a lot but haven't found a solution.

```
dependencies { implementation(name: "truesdk-0.7-releasePartner", ext: "aar") }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a mismatch in the file provided with TC Sdk and the documentation,
Basically the file name is truesdk-v0.7-releasePartner.aar, while the name as mentioned in documentation is truesdk-0.7-releasePartner.

You need to add 'v' before '0.7' while mentioning the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try looking at the documentation mentioned here? It explains exactly how you can integrated the SDK to your Android app. (Step 2 on **Using the SDK with your Android Studio Project** )
https://github.com/truecaller/android-sdk

---

Specifically on your issue, it looks like you've not added the SDK `aar` to your `lib` folder. The SDK aar itself can be obtained along with the partner key and access credentials when you sign up as a developer here (https://developer.truecaller.com/ ) and add your app details.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the the aar file and add into the project by *File > New Module > Import .jar/.aar Package*.
and then add `implementation "com.truecaller.android.sdk:truecaller-sdk:0.8"`
Here is the link for the [latest truecaller SDK](https://truecaller4developers.gitbook.io/truecallersdk/v/1.0/android/integrating-with-your-app)-

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone, as other answers provided here did not work for me

Go to `File->New->New Module`

Select the `"Import .JAR/.AAR Package"` item and click next button

go to `Project Structure (Ctrl+alt+shift+s)` select `dependencies` from `left panel` click on `+` icon from `declared dependencies` select `module dependency` there you can see your `Truecaller` dependency, click on it and Voila! Done.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your **`build.gradle`**(root) file.

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest sdk

```
implementation "com.truecaller.android.sdk:truecaller-sdk:0.8"
```