# Unable to compile Trucaller SDK

Tags: android, truesdk

I am trying to add the truecaller sdk. But I'm facing this error:

> Failed to resolve: :truesdk-0.7-releasePartner

I have Googled it a lot but haven't found a solution.

```
dependencies { implementation(name: "truesdk-0.7-releasePartner", ext: "aar") }
```

This guy asked the same, though the person who answered didn't work.
[Failed to resolve: :truesdk-0.7-releasePartner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881249/failed-to-resolve-truesdk-0-7-releasepartner)

Comment: maybe this can help https://github.com/truecaller/android-sdk
 check Minimum SDK version is atleast API level 16 or above ( Android 4.1 )
make fingerprint for the app (code is shown in the url above)
and add the required codes in the build.gradle

Comment: @Akshay, have you added in application module **repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}**

Comment: @R.F Already did it! Didn't help

Comment: @NiravBhavsar yes I have! Didn't help

Comment: Did everything according to the documentation..still no progress

Comment: @NiravBhavsar Do you have a solution? I think the documentation needs to update...as the latest android studio release might not be supporting the dependency. I'm not sure, but maaybe

Comment: @AkshayKrishna, Sorry mate, i have do not have any solutions.

Comment: Please check my answer you will get your answer-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58057556/9187714

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me!!

I renamed the `aar` file to `truesdk-v0.7-releasepartner.aar` inside `libs` folder instead of `truesdk-0.7-releasePartner.aar(given on truecaller github)`

and also renamed in the `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**
You have to download the the aar file and add into the project by *File > New Module > Import .jar/.aar Package*.
and then add `implementation "com.truecaller.android.sdk:truecaller-sdk:0.8"`
Here is the link for the [latest truecaller SDK](https://truecaller4developers.gitbook.io/truecallersdk/v/1.0/android/integrating-with-your-app)-